# .Net connection pool causing login failed after SQL Server password change

Tags: .net, sql-server, authentication, connection, pool

We have connection strings in our config files which don't contain passwords.

```
Data Source=OurDataSource;Initial Catalog=OurCatalog;Integrated Security=False;UID=OurUser;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;
```

In our code the password is loaded from a service and appended as follows:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ourCS"].ConnectionString;
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var credential = GetPassword(builder.UserID);
builder.Password = credential.Password;
var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Execute our query
}
```

The password service changes the password each few months and recently after a password change we started receiving login failed errors below and the account locked out.

```
Login failed for user 'OurUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.
```

My research points to problems with the connection pool which has still has open connections which try to authenticate against the db and lock it.

All of our db communication is done in using statements above which should close the connection when dispose is called. However, after decompiling System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, it seems the dispose method doesn't close the connection.

```
public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // using CloseHandle and UnmapViewOfFile - no exposure
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.Machine)]
        private void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing) {
               // Nothing to do here
                ;
            }
            if (pMemMap != IntPtr.Zero) {
                NativeMethods.UnmapViewOfFile(pMemMap);
                pMemMap = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            if (hMemMap != IntPtr.Zero) {
                NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hMemMap);
                hMemMap = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            active = false;
        }

        ~SqlDebugContext() {
                Dispose(false);
        }
```

Has anyone come across this issue and a solution to it? At the moment it points to having to call connection close as follows as it doesn't seem Dispose does it.

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Execute our query
db.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disposing a pooled connection just returns it to the pool. Since each connection pool is a distinct connection string, a new pool will be created when a connection string when a new password is used.

I suspect the problem is one of timing, where the original password is retrieved and used repeatedly so the account is locked out before the new password is retrieved from the service to build a new connection string.

If the password change is a manual process (e.g. 'ALTER LOGIN') and then the service configured with the new password, a solution could be to change the password in the service code using the static [`SqlConnection.ChangePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb8k729z.aspx) method. I think that would mitigate the problem as long as there is only one instance of the service.

Comment: I thought it might have been timing but it wasn't as it went on for two days where we saw login fail and login success in our sql logs. Unfortunately we don't have access to change the password ourselves.

Comment: @AndyKing, no special permissions are needed to change the password. Just specify a connection string containing the old password along with the new password to the ChangePassword method.

Comment: The ChangePassword method wont help as we store connStrings without passwords for security. It only works if you have the current password populated "The connection string must contain the user ID and the current password." Each request doesn't know what the password is until the service returns it for security.

Comment: ALso special permissions are needed to change the password as it's a dbreader and writer account only. Furthermore we don't want to change the password as this is controlled centrally by a service.

Comment: @AndyKing, I mean the service can invoke the ChangePassword method and return the new password to the client app.

Comment: No need as the service already has a mechanism to do this and return the password. This doesn't relate to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above should dispose the SqlConnection and create a new connection each time that a connection to the database is made. The connection string used for the first connection is not being cached anywhere, and a new SqlConnection is being created with the `connectionString` variable that you pass it.

Based upon the symptoms you describe, it seems that the `GetPassword` method is not consistently returning the correct username password combination.

It's possible that this is a timing issue like @DanGuzman described, where the `GetPassword` function returns the correct password, but the password is changed before the SqlConnection is created. This would explain the intermittent login successes and failures that are logged.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have now found the answer. I have a customer log4net appender which gets the connection string and adds the password from the service.

The problem was I was retrieving the password in the constructor of our custom appender and the constructor is only called on app start :D. Therefore I had to move the retrieval of the password in the overridden append method.

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RepositoryAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RepositoryAppender" type="MyAppender, MyLibrary">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
    </appender>
</log4net>
```