# Occasional random C# crash when accessing SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, crash, sql-server-2019

I have an application that never had issues on SQL Server 2012, but now it occasionally crashes when trying to access SQL Server 2019 on startup.

Here is the event log:

```
Application: MyApplication.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Object, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
   at MyApplication.Program.MyDatabaseMethod(System.String)
   at MyApplication.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Here is the method that it crashes on:

```
public static string MyDatabaseMethod()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM mydatabase.dbo.mytable";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, myConnectionString);

    da.Fill(dt);

    string data = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("col1");
    return data;
}
```

This works 90% of the time, but the occasional crash is becoming problematic. Does the error look like a timeout? The database is very busy and has multiple instances (~20) of this application connecting at the same time each night, so I am wondering if there is some concurrency issue with that many logins at once. The query itself is accessing a table with no more than 30 rows.

Comment: Captuing the exception's `Message` might be nice; why not put a `try/catch` into your code so the whole thing doesn't die in a heap if the DB isn't available?

Comment: Maybe this will explain what is happening : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250376/net-connection-pool-causing-login-failed-after-sql-server-password-change

Comment: *some concurrency issue with that many logins at once* - probably not, given the enterprise-grade nature of the database.. 30 connections is small fry. A query that uses TOP without ORDER BY is nonsensical, by the way

Comment: Agreed on the ORDER BY missing. The query was simplified for demonstration.

Should I be disposing the `SqlDataAdapter`? I was under the impression this was not required based on how I was using it.

Comment: capturing the exception using **TRY-CATCH** or try running a trace in the DB to see whether the issue is within the DB.